# Monotouch iphone custom UITableView

Tags: c#, iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I followed [this](http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/05/uitableview-with-custom-uitableviewcell.html) tutorial in order to create a custom Cell.

I have created a custom cell in the Interface Builder that looks like that:
[image]

In my ViewController i have added a UITableView and bind it to a data:

```
myTable.Source = new ListSource();
```

The GetCell method of the ListSource:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    { 
        // Reuse a cell if one exists 
        CustomListCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("QCell") as CustomQuestionsListCell;

        if (cell == null)
        {  
            // We have to allocate a cell 
            var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("CustomListCell", tableView, null); 
            cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as CustomListCell;
        } 

        return cell; 
    }
```

The problem is that the display in the end looks like that:

[image]

It seems like there some kind of over lapping. Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the table view's [`RowHeight`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.RowHeight) to whatever the view height is in IB.  This should be `myTable.RowHeight = ...`.

If you have different heights for each row, you can use [`GetHeightForRow`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewDelegate.GetHeightForRow%28MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView%2cMonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath%29) in the delegate but this is much slower, causing the table view to iterate through all cells before the first rendering (so it can calculate scroll height).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the RowHeight for the Custom Cell your are using in your project . Since your are not providing any height , the Table is allocating default to the TableViewCell . RowHeight provided by you should be same as that in the Interface Builder (IB) .